# Workaround for program requiring CD Burner

Tags: optical-media

I have a program that allows me to download data if I burn it to a CD. Unfortunately I don't own any CD burners anymore, and can't use this feature.

Does anyone know how to:

- Imitate a CD Burner but instead write to disk.
- do any thing else that will help.

Answer (score 1):

[SuperUser SE](https://superuser.com/questions/126571/i-would-like-to-burn-a-file-to-a-virtual-dvd) had a similar post. The trick was figuring out the search terms.

The link suggests two programs, [TotalMounter (free)](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/totalmounter-free-virtual-cddvd-burner-thats-easy-use.htm) and [VirtualCD](https://www.virtualcd-online.com/) (no price without filling form), both of which specifically address the capacity to burn as if it was a physical drive.